# What happens when I grab a hanging rope mid-jump?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Suppose I'm flying through the air after a jump, and grab the end of a rope that's hanging straight down. At the moment I grab the rope, I have a certain velocity vector $v$ and am only under the influence of gravity. What kind of trajectory do I follow after grabbing the rope?

For instance, suppose the vertical component of $v$ is negative (downward). Does the rope just instantaneously zero out the vertical component of $v$, while leaving the horizontal component intact? If the vertical component of $v$ is positive, do I continue to move in a parabola, unaffected by the rope until it becomes taught?

Comment: If the rope just instantaneously zero out the vertical component of v, it would break anyway. The force would be infinite. But your hands and arms would not resist an infinite force. Every change of velocity needs time, otherwise the acceleration and the force must be infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've a very strong grip the most likely result is you continuing your trajectory practically unchanged.  The word "splat" comes to mind. :-)

Assuming you have a fabulous grip ...

You and the rope become one.

At this point the sudden addition of your momentum could break the rope, as could the stress of your combined motion.  Again .. splat. :-)

Let's assume this is a stubborn rope that can hold itself together ...

The rope and you now share your momentum when you made your grip.

The rope is presumed to be secure somewhere and you'll basically become a pendulum.  Swinging back or forth.  It's possible your momentum is enough to create a more drastic swing to the near vertical, but assuming you can hang on and the rope doesn't finally break under this tension, you will settle into a pendulum-like motion which will diminish over time.

Precisely what kind of motion that will result depends on the details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. And yes.

And after saying that, remember that these are idealizations. Your body will use joints to flex the change in speed components, and slight elasticity of the rope will as well. Regarding the positive vertical component causing no change and just an unaltered parabola curve, this is likewise assuming a mass-less rope.